# Is it necessary to memorise physics derivation? Or solving problem is important?

Tags: soft-question, education

I am a undergraduate physics student of open university I am in fear that I may forget derivation and even I already forget some of derivation of oscillation and waves but while I was learning them I understood each step and I can apply these formulas to solve problem.My question is it necessary to know and remember each step of derivation.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic on this Q&A site because it's not about physics. It's also very subjective as to what things need to be memorised depending upon what your reason for studying physics is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not always necessary. There are a few important derivations which you should have by heart (EOM of a harmonic oscillator in 1D for example) but that will happen automatically with time and practice. The most important thing to remember is the physics behind the system you are studying.
One of my teachers in school once told us that in Physics you first have to "frame the problem" in terms of mathematical equations and from there on "it's just math". Once you have expressed your system in proper equations and made necessary approximations wherever needed, I think you can easily work through the calculations to arrive at the desired result.
You should not really worry about memorising derivations. If you ever see someone who can do derivations from memory then that is either a lot of practice or bad [study] practice. So, no pressure.
All the best for your future!

Answer (score 5):

You should *understand* the derivations. Once you understand you can easily recreate them when you need them. Memorising without understanding is a useless strategy.

Comment: One reason that I've been able to build a career in physics is that I have a very poor memory.  I'd never make it as a chemist or biologist.  However, it is a struggle to remember authors' names, or where I saw something published, or what I had for breakfast.

Comment: I’d like to explicitly state what mike has said. You need to understand why it is derived in the way it is, and not just the how. You need to understand the underlying physics and not just the mathematical steps. Then you can reproduce them at your will.

Comment: @garyp its inspiring I have same condition of poor memory

Comment: It's worth reading up on strategies for improving recall of information. Especially if you're someone who has labelled themselves as "bad at remembering", chances are you aren't just biologically deficient at information recall and would benefit a lot from having an actual strategy for storing new information.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Stone's answer is right, there are some things in physics (and in any field of science in general) that are just worth being able to regurgitate, for instance the value of some constants to a few decimal places. Learning something like the Schrodinger equation, which you probably don't want to have to elaborately rederive every time you use it would be helpful too.

With mathematical derivations you'll be doing yourself a much greater service by remembering **why** you perform each step, and why it moves you closer to the result you're trying to obtain. Recognising and learning the general strategy being applied in a derivation will be of more value and have more general application than just remembering what you write down at each step.